# TintColor Changing on Popover Push

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, tintcolor

I'm setting the tint color of a window to an arbitrary color, then trying to over-ride this on a per-button basis, but it appears that the buttons revert to the window tint color whenever there is a segue applied on them.

Setting tint color in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

and then my two buttons in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.button1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"711-trash"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.button1.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

self.button2.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

where button1 is a custom type button and button2 is a system type button.

[image]

When the popover first presents, the two buttons are tinted purple and blue.  But when the segue view controller is pushed, the popped, the two buttons switch to red.  Is there any way to prevent this?

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Have you tired to set the colors in viewWillAppear?

Comment: @Leonardo same issue, doesn't appear to be affected by viewWillAppear

Comment: It's weird, is there any chance you set tintColor somewhere else?

Comment: @user3779315 I can set the tint color wherever, but any time I do the same behavior takes hold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried reproducing your code like this:

[image: Storyboard & code]

However everything worked as expected:

[image: Result on simulator]

So I agree with @user3779315, possibly you are setting the buttons' tint color somewhere else. Btw, additional code of your project would help to clarify the issue :-)

Comment: hey @Ducky thanks for your reply - did you set the window tint color in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?  And did the code also work on the iPad simulator?

Comment: Yes I did   `self.window.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];`  :)  Otherwise you can't see the buttons with red tintColor as in the screenshots

Comment: good point... How about the iPad simulator? When I test with the iPhone the intended behavior works correctly but the iPad doesn't

Comment: I tested on iPad actually. I didn't post the screenshots of iPad simulator but same results

Comment: super weird, the sample code I posted is the only code in my project and it doesn't work.

Comment: Here was the dead simple project I created when trying to reproduce your issue: https://gitlab.com/dobaduc/PopOverTint.   It works on Xcode GM... What iOS version are you using to test?

Comment: That might be the difference, using 8.4 to test. Tested your project and it looks like it displays the same bug under that OS

Comment: I see. I will try later on iOS 8.4. But it looks like an issue that Apple knew and fixed :)